# Is making images for game development prohibited in islam

Tags: halal-haram, game, software, drawing, art

Assalamu alaykum my brothers, I've been surfing the internet about if it's halal to draw such human images with facial expressions, but I don't know if some facial expressions such as 2 pixels representing an eye of a character permissible or not, Since they're some simple pixels that don't come with the advanced tiered drawings of advanced eyes (Example: the image below).
Also is it permissible to make my character *completely* animated? In addition, some say that it's permissible to draw In virtual (Computers) and not in reality.
**To sum up**, is it permissible to draw a character such as the image below with SIMPLE facial expressions? is it fine if the character doesn't come close to a real human being? Jazak'umullah khairan..

[image: Frisk from undertale]

Answer (score 0):

> Bismihi ta'ala
>
> There would be no problem with drawing or painting. Such an art is a
> valued talent and indeed must be appreciated.
>
> A problem would arise if:
>
> 1. You are making full sculptures of humans or animals. If it is something that has a "soul", then it is not permitted to make a
>    sculpture of it.
> 2. It is a promoting of anything that represents any deviancy, immorality, or anything un-Islamic.
>
> And Allah knows best.

https://www.al-islam.org/ask/as-an-artist-what-would-be-considered-shirk-in-what-i-draw